# Unable to log into Synology NAS using new SSH key

Tags: ssh, synology

I've been using SSH to connect to my Synology for ages. Recently, I've generated a new `id_rsa` key and copied the pubkey to the Synology's `.ssh/authorized_keys`. Unfortunately, the new key always prompts for password:

```
❯ ssh -vvv nas
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/andig/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/andig/.ssh/config line 14: Applying options for nas
debug1: /Users/andig/.ssh/config line 68: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to nas port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/andig/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to nas:22 as 'admin'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/andig/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/andig/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from nas
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:a4IWJIsXBhxFEclMSEupFvwvybft5WI8xb8R/8/DhO8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/andig/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/andig/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from nas
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/andig/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/andig/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.0.41
debug1: Host 'nas' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/andig/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xlawB7MAGNbHr5bGC7vIEag9s9tjfOo7Jc9ERHbJ6X8
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xlawB7MAGNbHr5bGC7vIEag9s9tjfOo7Jc9ERHbJ6X8
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/andig/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
admin@nas's password:
```

Switching back to the old key works fine. New key on different machine (Raspi) works fine, too.

I'm unable to figure out why the new key doesn't work on the Syno?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the information. But if the old one is still working, then my first guess is: are they on separate lines?

Comment: What options are referenced in `debug1: /Users/andig/.ssh/config line 14: Applying options for nas`? Specifically have you defined a key there?

Comment: The option was the admin username for the nas host

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the `authorized_keys` file was corrupt:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y...
ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1k...
ssh-rsa 
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAA...
ssh-rsa 
AAAAB3NzaC1...
```

It seems as if just pasting the key did introduce a line break after the key type identifier. I didn't notice first when using `nano` on the file as it looked like a natural work wrap to me.